# Stop countdown timer at 0

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown timer that is working, but I cannot figure out how to get it to stop at 0.

Here's what I have:

```
let totalTime = 10;
let timeElapsed = 0;
let interval;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let currentAnswer = 0;


function startTimer() {
    runTimer.textContent = totalTime;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        totalTime--;
        runTimer.textContent = totalTime;
        }
, 1000);
    if (interval <= 0) {
        stopTimer(); 
    }
}


function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

I tried creating an if statement to clearInterval once the timer reaches 0 but something is not right.

Comment: you're not checking if the time has reached zero, you're checking if the `interval` is less than or equal to zero, which it won't ever be, since setInterval returns a number (that never changes) that is always greater than 0. You need to check if `totalTime <= 0`

Comment: I tried that as well but still having the same issue

Comment: you probably tried wrong ... check INSIDE the interval code, not outside

Comment: Oh okay, yeah that worked moving it inside the interval section. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if totalTime is <= 0 but inside the setInterval function like this.

```
function startTimer() {
    runTimer.textContent = totalTime;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        totalTime--;
        runTimer.textContent = totalTime;
        if (totalTime <= 0) {
          stopTimer();
        }
     } , 1000);
}
```